# link table in cakephp and habtm

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.3, join

Before any advice to read google and etc, i must write that i read a lot of articles and blogs, and for now i cant figure out how to use HABTM in my case... ;]

I have order system with 3 tables and 3 models:

1. ORDERS (order_id, customer_id, paymenyOption, etc...)
2. ITEMS (item_id, size, color, etc...)
3. CUSTOMERS (customer_id, name, telephone, etc...)

For now i have relationship between ORDERS<->CUSTOMERS (which works fine), but i need to have 'link table' in which will be `order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`.

To be clear,

- one order can have many items
- one items can be in many orders
- one customer can have many orders (but one order can have one customer)

  (normal order-system philoshopy)

In order view i must have details for 'item', 'customer', and 'order', something like:

```
Name: Johny Deep (from CUSTOMERS model)
Date ordered: 13-08-2013 (from ORDERS model)
Products: 2x apple, 2x watermelon (from ITEMS model)
```

I dont know if i must use hasMany or hasAndBelongsTo, and make another model for 'link table'?

Can anyone explain me this beautiful sh** in cakephp 2.x ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unique about this situation that you couldn't find elsewhere.

Using model name instead

```
Order (order_id, customer_id, paymentOption, etc...)
Item (item_id, size, color, etc...)
Customer (customer_id, name, telephone, etc...)
OrderItem (order_id, item_id)
```

Relationships

```
Order belongsTo Customer
Order hasMany OrderItem
Item hasMany OrderItem
Customer hasMany Order
OrderItem belongsTo Order
OrderItem belongsTo Item
```

If you are looking up details on an order you can do

```
find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Order.id' => $order_id // which would have to be defined earlier, perhaps from a param passed in the route
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Customer',
        'OrderItem => array(
            'Item'
        )
    )
));
```

Likewise, it is very easy to pull up all orders by Customer, all order by specific Item, the sum of times a customer has placed an order, the sum of times an Item has been ordered, and the sum of times a customer has ordered a specific item, etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

@bowlerae:
I found this solution earlier, and it works in 50% in my query, i have code:

```
$products = $this->Order->find('first', array(

            'contain' => array (
                'Customer',
                'OrderItem' => array(
                    'Item'
                )
            )
                 ));
```

above (i omit array 'Order' and 'Customer' - are no important now):

```
array(

'OrderItem' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '4',
            'quantity' => '2',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '6',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '7',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '8',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        )
    )
)
```

1.So how can I get all 'products' now ? i started with something similar to this but i know that it is bad because i must write ['0']...['1]... which is dynamic variable

```
<?php echo h($products['OrderItem']['0']['item_id']); ?>
```

2.As you can see

> 'Item' => array()

is null ;-) so i cant get for example the name of the item from a Item table/model